# Why is one type of parsed string echoed in the wrong place?

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm working on a format toolbar on a website that uses BBCode, and use the following code to parse certain formatting tags before echoing my content:

```
$content = htmlspecialchars($row['postContent'], ENT_QUOTES);

//Parse BB Code
$patterns = array
(
    "#\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]#",
    "#\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]#",
    "#\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]#",    
    "#\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]#"                                       
);

$replacements = array
(
    "<b>$1</b>",
    "<i>$1</i>",
    "<u>$1</u>",
    "<blockquote class=\"user-quote\"><p class=\"quote-text\">$1</p></blockquote>"                          
);

$content = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $content);
```

The problem I'm having is that the final tag is not being echoed in the proper place. I currently have all of the `$row['postContent']` echoed inside the following HTML:

```
<div class="text">                                           
    <p id="'.$row['postID'].'">
        '.$content.'
    </p>
</div>
```

All of the format tags (including others that I have not shown in this post) are put inside the `<p id="blah"></p>` element, and are thus formatted according to my CSS styling for paragraph elements. For some reason `<blockquote class=\"user-quote\"><p class=\"quote-text\">$1</p></blockquote>` is being echoed after these tags, and when I view the code in the inspector it looks like:

```
<div class="text">                                           
    <p id="blah">

    </p>
    <div class="user-quote">
      ::before
        <p class="quote-text">foo bar</p>
      ::after
    </div>        
</div>
```

Strangely enough, if I view the source code for the page it appears to be echoed correctly, but this isn't the case in the inspector, and it certainly looks incorrect on my page, especially if I include regular text that isn't inside BBCode tags. If I do this, I get a strange "phantom" `<p></p>` at the end of the div:

```
<div class="text">                                           
    <p id="blah">

    </p>
    <div class="user-quote">
      ::before
        <p class="quote-text">foo bar</p>
      ::after
    </div>  
    "
    here is some non-formatted text

    "
    <p></p>      
</div>
```

I've tried a bunch of things, like removing certain CSS styling (I thought that `::before` or `::after` was the culprit) and changing my tags from `<blockquote>` to `<div>`, but nothing is working. Why could this happen? Maybe my fatigue has caused me to miss something very obvious.

If it helps, this is the exact content I'm trying to echo from the database:

```
[quote]some text[/quote]

here is some non-formatted text
```

[EDIT] If I switch the formatting of the content around...

```
here is some non-formatted text

[quote]some text[/quote]
```

...then the correct result is produced. I'm still not sure why this works, or why the other formatting produces an incorrect result. I would certainly like users to be able to post regular text after the quote tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly debugged the problem by saying `if I view the source code for the page it appears to be echoed correctly, but this isn't the case in the inspector,`

The HTML inspector is NOT the HTML used to generate the page, but is how the browser has managed to determine what needs to be shown.

If you look at the specs for "P" elements - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p - you'll see that if you follow `<p>` with `<blockquote>` then it assumes the `<p>` is closed, thus you'll see in the inspector `<p></p><blockquote>blah</blockquote>` (followed by a `</p>` that it doesn't know what to do with and may use or may have discarded and may or may not show in inspector - not really sure).

Comment: I did not know this. However, I'm not sure this solves my problem because changing the tags to something other than `<blockquote>` still produces the same result, even if all CSS styling is removed. It just makes no sense that this particular parse refuses to be echoed in the correct spot. Do you think I need to change the echo tags to something like `<span>`?

Comment: Alright, after thinking about it for a moment this answer got me where I needed to go. I had to change my echo tags to `<div>` for my quotes and text to be displayed properly.

Comment: Tip would be to always use `div`s for your layout like that if you need a block element, unless you specifically were putting in a paragraph of text (where it's semantically correct and accessibly correct to use the `p`). Glad you sorted it out. At least the HTML spec is now free-er than it used to be!