# How can I capture and format on output nested format tags?

Tags: php, regex, nested, forum

I'm working on a forum system that parses BBCode like `[b]some bold text[/b]` and applies HTML formatting to it when output via PHP. All of my expressions work, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to deal with a certain scenario, specifically regarding nested quote blocks.

On a forum you might have one user quote another user. I have been successful at formatting this using:

`#\[quote="(.*?);(\w*?)"\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/quote\]#`

and calling `preg_replace()` to replace it with:

`<blockquote id="quote-$2"><p>$3<br> - $1</p></blockquote>` Here is a [working example](https://regex101.com/r/Z0N8Vf/2).

For a real example you might see on a forum, a user, `Stan`, wants to quote `John`, adding this to a textarea for submission:

```
[quote="John;2"]John's sentence[/quote] 
____________

Stan's reply
```

But what happens if John had quoted Mary in his post?

```
[quote="John;2"][quote="Mary;1"]Mary's sentence[/quote]John's sentence[/quote]
____________

Stan's reply
```

My regex will capture all but the last `[/quote]`, but even if I was able to capture the whole string I'm not sure how I'd be able to format it. Ideally, I'd like the output to look something like this:

```
    "Mary's sentence"          
        - Mary

"John's sentence"
    - John
__________________________

Stan's reply
```

In HTML:

```
<blockquote id="quote-2">
    <blockquote id="quote-1"><p>"Mary's sentence"<br> - Mary</p></blockquote>
        <p>"John's sentence"<br> - John</p>
</blockquote> 
<p>Stan's reply</p>
```

Can I capture and format repeated nested tags using regex? What if there are 100 nested quote blocks? Obviously I can just write a ridiculously long and repetitive expression (which certainly would have limitations), but there has to be a better way to tackle this. Is there another method I should use?

I'm sorry if a [similar question already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns), but I have looked through many questions on SO and am still not sure which approach I should take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to make sure you only match the innermost BB tag. Match all text between `[quote` and `[/quote]` that dooes not contain another `[quote=`, and replace until no such match is found. It is also based on an assumption you have no `[quote=` in your actual tag contents, but in most cases it is true. Another assumption is that the attributes are `"`-quoted and there cannot be other double quotes inside.

So, you may use

```
$s = '[quote="John;2"][quote="Mary;1"]Mary\'s sentence[/quote]John\'s sentence[/quote]';
$repl = '<blockquote id="quote-$2"><p>$3 <br> - $1</p></blockquote>';
$reg = '~\[quote="([^"]*);(\w*)"]\s*((?:(?!\[quote=).)*?)\s*\[/quote]~si';
while (preg_match($reg, $s)) {
    $s = preg_replace($reg, $repl, $s);
}
echo $s;
// => <blockquote id="quote-2"><p><blockquote id="quote-1"><p>Mary's sentence <br> - Mary</p></blockquote>John's sentence <br> - John</p></blockquote>
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/feRjfS). The regex is

```
'~\[quote="([^"]*);(\w*)"]\s*((?:(?!\[quote=).)*?)\s*\[/quote]~si'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z0N8Vf/3).

**Details**

- `\[quote="` - a literal substring
- `([^"]*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `;` - a colon
- `(\w*)` - Capturing group 2: 0+ word chars
- `"]` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `((?:(?!\[quote=).)*?)` - Capturing group 3: any char, as few as possible, not starting `[quote=` text
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\[/quote]` - a literal `[/quote]` substring.

Pretty-printing is an extra task, there are [a couple of solutions mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768215/php-pretty-print-html-not-tidy).

Comment: [DIndent](https://github.com/gajus/dindent) is another suggested library for indentation.

Comment: Also, here is an attempt to get the [exact expected format](https://ideone.com/8yrNTv).

Comment: Thank you again, Wiktor, for your regex assistance. This is exactly what I wanted, and I appreciate the detailed explanation.

Comment: For anybody who may see this in the future, you can't use the `<p>` element with this technique because it won't render correctly in the browser. A [related question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412794/why-is-one-type-of-parsed-string-echoed-in-the-wrong-place) has more on why this happens.